Bad SQL grammar error in spring boot h2 in memory database
I am writing a simple CRUD API using spring boot. I just connected to h2 console. The 'schema.sql' file loads correctly and data is inserted from the 'data.sql' file in the TRANSACTION table. But after insertion I can not get the JSON from the page. It says bad sql grammar error. I don't know what should I do. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code for the TranscationController.java
package com.zsgs.expenz.transaction;

import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/transactions")
public class TransactionController {

    private final TransactionRepository transactionRepository;

    public TransactionController(TransactionRepository transactionRepository) {
        this.transactionRepository = transactionRepository;
    }


    @GetMapping("")
    List<Transaction> findAll() {
        return transactionRepository.findAll();
    }

}

Here is my TransactionRepository.java
package com.zsgs.expenz.transaction;

import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.JdbcClient;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public class TransactionRepository {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TransactionRepository.class);
    private final JdbcClient jdbcClient;

    public TransactionRepository(JdbcClient jdbcClient) {
        this.jdbcClient = jdbcClient;
    }

    public List<Transaction> findAll() {
        return jdbcClient.sql("SELECT * FROM TRANSACTION").query(Transaction.class).list();
    }
}

Here is my schema.sql file
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TRANSACTION (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    transaction_name varchar(250) NOT NULL,
    t_date timestamp NOT NULL,
    cost INT NOT NULL,
    transaction_type varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
  );

data.sql file
INSERT INTO TRANSACTION (id, transaction_name, t_date, cost, transaction_type)
VALUES (1, 'Grocery', '2024-06-07 06:00:00', 400, 'EXPENDITURE');

Transaction.java file
package com.zsgs.expenz.transaction;

import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Positive;

import java.util.Date;

public record Transaction(
      Integer id,
      @NotEmpty
      String transactionName,
      Date tDate,
      @Positive
      Integer cost,
      TransactionType type
) {}



Which dbms are you using?

I don't know if wildcard is appropriate in select statement with conversion to class, so I would try to enumerate all fields as select id, transaction_name,  ... from transaction My boss prohibit me to use wildcards in select statements, as they can supply more fields then required

@jarlh only testing with h2 console

TRANSACTION might be a reserved word, depending on dbms. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SQL_reserved_words. Try "TRANSACTION" etc.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Instead, [edit] your question to include the code as properly formatted text.
